# more objects in one json file

Tags: jquery, json

I am developing a mapping tool, and I am using jQuery to download JSON data from a server. the code for the jquery is currently:

```
$.getJSON("start.json", function(data) {
    var items = [];

    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        alert("data: " + key + "->" + val);
    });
});
```

the json file looks like this:

```
{
    "type"  :   "obstacle",
    "top"   :   20,
    "left"  :   10,
    "height":   50,
    "width" :   70,
    "tall"  :   10
}
```

now, the "problem" is that, as it can be seen clearly, in this format, the json can only contain one object. how do I have to structure my file (and consequently my jquery) to have more than one object?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at NDJSON, Newline Delimited JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array to store them:

```
{
  "objects": [
    {
      "type"  :   "obstacle",
        "top"   :   20,
        "left"  :   10,
        "height":   50,
        "width" :   70,
        "tall"  :   10
      }, {
      "type"  :   "obstacle",
        "top"   :   20,
        "left"  :   10,
        "height":   50,
        "width" :   70,
        "tall"  :   10
      }, {
      "type"  :   "obstacle",
        "top"   :   20,
        "left"  :   10,
        "height":   50,
        "width" :   70,
        "tall"  :   10
      }
    ]
}
```

Now, when you iterate, you can access an individual object's properties:

```
$.each(data.objects, function(key, val) {
  console.log(key + ' => ' + val);
});
```

Comment: great! what about the jquery?

Comment: Well, `data.objects` will be an array that stores all of the objects. Iterate over it and `console.log()` some stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an array of JSON objects like this:

```
[
    { 
        "type"  :   "obstacle", 
        "top"   :   20, 
        "left"  :   10, 
        "height":   50, 
        "width" :   70, 
        "tall"  :   10 
    } ,
    { 
        "type"  :   "obstacle", 
        "top"   :   50, 
        "left"  :   10, 
        "height":   50, 
        "width" :   20, 
        "tall"  :   10 
    } 
]
```

**Edit: jQuery would be something like:**

```
$.each(data, function(index, obstacle))
{
    $.each(obstacle, function(key, val) { 
        alert("data: " + key + "->" + val); 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: I am getting an alert with: `data: 0->[object Object]`