# Can a json file contain more than one object?

Tags: json

Can a json file contain more than one object?

For example, can the content of a json file be two objects as the following?

```
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}
```

Some experienced software engineer said that a json file could only contain one object, although other objects could be nested in the object.

Thanks.

Comment: Pretty close to a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025299/more-objects-in-one-json-file.

Comment: No. But have a look at NDJSON, Newline Delimited JSON. A .ndjson file allows multiple json objects in a single file where each json object is delimited with a newline character.

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't look much like json, but yes, you can totally have an array of objects in json file. Something like this in your case:

```
[{"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith"},       
{"firstName": "Jane", "lastName": "Doe"}]
```

A json file may either contain a single object in (which can be complex, with many nested keys) or an array of such objects. It's either curly braces or square brackets on the outside.

Comment: Thanks. Can the outmost pair of brackets be removed? See my edited example, i.e. the objects are not inside one pair of brackets/braces.

Comment: The outer delimiter will either be curly brace for an entity or a dictionary of entities or a square bracket for an array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can have:

`JSONObject = {
   ObjectOne: {
      property1: value1
   },
   ObjectTwo: {
      property1: value2
   },
   someProperty: value3,
   ....
}`

EDIT: You can also have an array of objects if that suits you better.

Comment: For this suggestion, do I need to save the JSON in an object? Or can it be like: 
{
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}
}